# Responsive font size for high resolutions not working in MUI 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, font-size

I am using [Material UI v5](https://mui.com/) in my React app.

And using [responsiveFontSizes](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#responsivefontsizes-theme-options-theme) to generate responsive typography settings based on the options received.

So the responsiveFontSizes works fine for all device sizes, but only for the default Material UI breakpoints.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVAVK.png)

The font sizes on a device which has a high or ultra high resolution like 2560 * 1440, 2340 * 1080 or even 3200 * 1440 don't work at all.

They look very small.

If I look into the inspect mode, then I can see a Typography with h3 has `2.9991rem` as maximum.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip2E8.png)

All of the Typography components I used in [Container](https://mui.com/components/container/#main-content).

```
<Container maxWidth="md">
  <Typography variant="h1">h1 test</Typography>
  ...
</Container>
```

How can I make the responsiveFontSizes work on a high resolution device as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue. if you check the https://mui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes there is chart which shows how `responsiveFontSizes()` displays. basically at lower screen resolutions higher fontsize shrinks faster compared to lower fontsize. so I skipped `responsiveFontSizes()` all together.

I wrote my custom typograhy tags with `rem` units w.r.t 1024px media breakpoint. the added breakpoint in `index.css` to increase the `html` `font-size`

**Option1: lower to higher screen resolution**

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import './index.css';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h1: {
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: '2.25rem',
      lineHeight: 2.75,
    },
    h2: {
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: '1.625rem',
      lineHeight: 2.125, 
    },
    ...
  },
});

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Typography variant="h1" color="primary">Heading 1</Typography>
      <Typography variant="h2" color="primary">Heading 2</Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

**index.css**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    html {
    font-size: 100%;
    }
  };
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    html {
    font-size: 125%;
    }
  };
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1536px) {
    html {
    font-size: 150%;
    }
  };
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    html {
    font-size: 187.5%;
    }
  };
```

**Options2: with responsiveFontSizes (higher to lower scrensizes) :**
for this you have to set `typography fontsize` based on the highest resolution. check https://mui.com/customization/theming/#responsivefontsizes-theme-options-theme for other options and further tweaking.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, responsiveFontSizes } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h1: { fontSize: '5rem' },
  },
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 425,
      md: 768,
      lg: 1024,
      xl: 1280,
      '2xl': 1536,
      '3xl': 1920,
      '4xl': 2560,
      '5xl': 3200,
    },
  },
});

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={responsiveFontSizes(theme, { breakpoints: ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl', '2xl', '3xl', '4xl', '5xl'], factor: 5 })}>
      <Typography variant="h1" color="primary">
        Heading 1
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h6" color="primary">
        Heading 6
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" color="primary">
        Body 1
      </Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible using theme?

Comment: above method is good, if you want to have responsive margins, height width etc. you can add them in rem units. another approach is use the media query inside H1,h2  tag but it will be repeated and lengthy.

Comment: please check the updated answer. added `responsiveFontSizes` method

Comment: Thank you, will try now and get back to you!

Comment: Hi, does this worked for you?

Comment: Yes, this worked.